# Convert string to decimal in C# not working

Tags: iis, decimal, cultureinfo

I need to convert a string to decimal.

And I'm baffled why it is not working

```
public ActionResult Test(){
            decimal result;
            bool o = decimal.TryParse("-2,366.15", out result);//false
            //decimal c = decimal.Parse("2,366.15", NumberStyles.AllowThousands,new CultureInfo("en-US"));

            var info = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            bool r = decimal.TryParse("2,366.15", 0, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result);//false
            bool t = decimal.TryParse("2,366.15", 0, info, out result);//false
            bool e = decimal.TryParse("2,366", 0, info, out result);//false
            bool f = decimal.TryParse("-2366.15", 0, info, out result);//false
            bool h = decimal.TryParse("2366", 0, info, out result);//true
            bool h2 = decimal.TryParse("2366,15", 0, info, out result);//false
            bool h3 = decimal.TryParse("2366.15", 0, info, out result);//false

            bool g = decimal.TryParse("2,366.15", 0, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out result);//false
            bool b = decimal.TryParse("2.366,15", out result);//true
}
```

b and h give true;

I'm working on a European version of IIS, so b is reads without problem.

However I am trying to convert "2,366.15" which is US use of decimal and comma for numbers. Why does adding the culture info, in all it's permutations above, not work?

Tx

Answer (score 0):

I use Convert to convert strings to decimal or other number values, so to support international formats this is what I use,

```
  Convert.ToInt32("56789"   , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  Convert.ToDouble("222,034", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

try

```
decimal.TryParse("2,3655.15", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. it does not accept 0 as an input for numberstyles

bool f = decimal.TryParse("-2366.15", **NumberStyles.Number**, info, out result);//false